# Advances in compiler and virtual machine technologies

Tags: articles, definite-article, zero-article

In [the official java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/intro/definition.html) we can read:

> However, advances in compiler and virtual machine technologies are bringing performance close to that of native code without threatening portability.

I have two questions:

1) Why the definite article was not used with "advances" ("the advances")? We are talking about advances in specified fields, not, for example, about advances in biology.

2) Finally, why the definite article was not used with "compiler and virtual machine technologies" ("the compiler and virtual machine technologies")? Again, we are talking about specified (by an adjective) technologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About your first question:
You did actually answer yourself; you said:

> We are talking about **advances** in specified fields, not, for example, about **advances** in biology.

Why didn't you add the article "the" although you were talking about some specific fields advances, in the first time? And about a particular field, in the second time?

The answer is simple: You specified what you were talking about that there wasn't a need for an article to define the two nouns when they have already been defined by what had followed them.

- The same is applied to your main sentence.

---

About your second question:

> ... in compiler and virtual machine technologies

If we were to add "the" before those two words, or at least before "compiler" which would refer to "virtual machine technologies" as well because of the conjunction "and", then it would be understood that we are talking about a **particular group** of compiler and VM technologies.

Without the article, it is understood as their preceding sentence is about compiler and VM technologies **in general**, not ones with some features and properties that have been mentioned/defined before. Otherwise, adding "the" would be necessary.

For example:

> Recently, some new virtual machine technologies have arisen. They are more efficient and productive than those regular ones as they have many unique features like: (the features are mentioned here). We predict that **the** virtual machine technologies will be introduced to the VM community soon.

I used "the" as I'm only referring to the VM technologies with the new, unique features, not all the VM technologies in the world.

Comment: I don't agree with the sentence: "You specified what you were talking about that there wasn't a need for an article to define the two nouns when they have already been defined by what had followed them". In "the book on the table" we have to use "the" before "table", though the noun has already been defined by what had followed it, the same in "the book in the room".

Comment: * before "book"

Comment: There are many situations where we should add articles before nouns, I have just mentioned the ones that fit your case. About "the book on the table", the article before "book" indicates a **specific** book that happened to be on a **known** table in that place. Thus, it is not **any** book, nor it is on **any** table but **that** book on **that** table. The same goes for "the book in the room".

Comment: So I could have written "the advances in compiler and virtual machine technologies" if I had meant more specific advances, for example, the advances in the current year?

Comment: Absolutely. If you are neither intending all the advances in compiler and VM technologies nor you are talking about them in general but some of them with particular properties, then use the article "the". However, you have to define/introduce them before using it, so the readers can know which compiler and VM you are intending by "the".

Comment: Could you answer my last question? Why the article headline on the website says: "About the Java Technology", but in the first sentence under the headline we read: "Java technology is both a programming language and a platform."? Why is the definite article in the headline used?

Comment: I almost forgot the part "technologies" that followed "compiler and virtual machine", but I have edited that although it doesn't really make a difference.

Comment: The writer wanted to talk about a particular matter/subject which is Java Technology. He used "the" to define the subject he was going to talk about. After it has been specified, he defined all the technologies that Java has, without excluding any. Thus, those two things don't relate to each other.

Comment: Does it mean that I could write "About the biology" in the headline when writing an article about biology to define the subject?

Comment: I'm glad you have mentioned this again since I've wanted to add something about it. "The" is really **optional** in that title and in yours. There may be a reason behind adding it when it is not necessary. I will ask about this on your behalf.

Comment: [Here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/199217/why-adding-the-article-the-when-it-is-not-needed/199222#199222) is the question. I hope you will find the answer there.

Comment: I have just noticed that in [the book version](https://www.amazon.com/The-Java-Tutorial-Course-Edition/dp/0134034082) of the tutorial the section "About the Java Technology" was replaced by the two subsections of the section from the online tutorial: "The Java Programming Language" and "The Java Platform". – piter00 4 mins ago

Comment: It seems that the writer uses the definite article excessively and that only proves/supports DavidK's point. Thus, avoid using "The" when it can be omitted unless you were very sure about your usage of it which would be the one that Mixolydian mentioned in his answer.