# Why adding the article "the" when it is not needed?

Tags: sentence-construction, usage, definite-article

There are many sentences, most are titles, that have **the** before nouns when they seem okay without it. I assume it is added to **over-define** them but not very sure.

[Here](https://www.clingendael.org/publication/government-people-people-people#) is a title that uses "the" excessively:

> GOVERNMENT OF **THE** PEOPLE, BY **THE** PEOPLE, FOR **THE** PEOPLE

"People" by itself is defined and doesn't need an article.

And [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/intro/definition.html) is another title that has the same issue:

> About **the** Java Technology

So, why it is added?

Comment: I think the second example may just be poor writing. The very next sentence is, "Java technology is both a programming language and a platform."

Comment: I find it the same as writing an article with a title like: "Let's talk about **the** weather". And then defining the weather -for some reasons- like this: Weather is climate conditions...etc. It wouldn't be: **The** weather is climate...etc

Comment: Maybe, except that "talk about the weather" has a specific idiomatic meaning. For example, if I say it rained in my town yesterday, I am talking about the weather. If it were normal to say, "The Java technology was particularly fine today," then "talking about the weather" would be a proper analogy for talking "about the Java technology."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Good question. When you say "*the* people", rather than just "people", the meaning is something like "all people" as opposed to "some people". That is,

> Government of people, by people, for people

would mean that the government is made up of and is intended for *some* people. That's not a very effective or inspiring message. I would also say that "the people" usually means "the common masses", as in, ordinary, non-elite people.

Also see definition 4 in Merriam-Webster, https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/the :

> used as a function word before a noun or a substantivized adjective to indicate reference to a group as a whole
>
> > // the elite

As for "the Java technology", I think that's more like definition 2a1 in Merriam-Webster (same link as above):

> used as a function word with a noun modified by an adjective or by an attributive noun to limit the application of the modified noun to that specified by the adjective or by the attributive noun
>
> > // the right answer
> >
> > // Peter the Great

"Java Technology" doesn't really have a different meaning from "the Java Technology", but I think the *the* emphasizes the fact that it is *Java* and not some other technology.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is - Emphasis

```
Dictionary result for emphasis
/ˈɛmfəsɪs/
noun
noun: emphasis; plural noun: emphases

    1.
    special importance, value, or prominence given to something.
    "they placed great emphasis on the individual's freedom"
    synonyms:   prominence, importance, significance; More
    stress, weight, attention, priority, urgency, force, forcibleness, insistence, underlining, underscoring, intensity;
    import, power, moment, mark, pre-eminence;
    weightage
    "the curriculum for 16-year-olds gave more emphasis to reading and writing"
    2.
    stress given to a word or words when speaking to indicate particular importance.
    "inflection and emphasis can change the meaning of what is said"
    synonyms:   stress, accent, accentuation, weight, force, prominence; More
    beat;
    ictus
    "the emphasis is on the word ‘little’"
        vigour or intensity of expression.
        "he spoke with emphasis and with complete conviction"
```

#### Example one, with the emphasis -

> GOVERNMENT OF THE PEOPLE, BY THE PEOPLE, FOR THE PEOPLE

The article "The" is used to signify that the Government that is made by (non-political/common) people, and only for people (and no one else). 'The' is talking about specific people. (This means people like the reader of the message)

#### However, without the emphasis -

> GOVERNMENT OF PEOPLE, BY PEOPLE, FOR PEOPLE

This is true for any government. As far as I know, there are no governments for aliens, by aliens or of aliens. Every government is of some people, by some people, and for some people.

Comment: Thank you for answering. You have attached all the possible meanings that would come out when using emphasis. Then, you explained that it is used for specification in example #1, but that wasn't mentioned in the gray box. So, could you clarify that more since I happened to think that too?

Comment: As both this and the slightly later answer explain, the meaning of a sentence can be changed significantly by replacing "people" by "the people." **That is not an example of "emphasis."** Setting a sentence in bold face, as I just did, is an example of emphasis.